# add_rewrite_rule and how to get the custom post into the worpress loop the correct way

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

I do have a plugin with an custom posttype "speaker" which can be reached with the normal permalink 
**domain.tld/speaker/speaker-name**.

In **addidtion** I want to use another url to reach the same speaker-name:

**domain.tld/slp/speaker-name**

so I used the rewrite_rule to mask the original url:

```
add_rewrite_rule('slp\/(.*)', 'index.php?slp=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

I know that I could simple rewrite it to the original permalink, but it is important that the user does not see the original permalink.

as next step I added the "slp" to the queryvars:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'queryvars' );
function queryvars( $qvars ){
  $qvars[] = 'slp';
  return $qvars;  
}
```

using the add_action("parse_request" ...) I tried to get control, and simply return an query with the correct post to Wordpress in the hope that its working:

```
add_action("parse_request", 'action_handler'); 
function action_handler($wp) {

  if (isset($wp->query_vars["slp"]))   {
      global $wp;
      $speaker_name = $wp->query_vars["slp"]; 
      ... some magic to get the $speaker_id as their is additional logic needed ...
      return query_posts('p='.$speaker_id.'&post_type=speaker');
  }
}
```

At first it looks like everything is working perfekt.. I can open the speaker post with both URL's but in the details it seems that i somehow "confused" the wordpress flow :(

For exmaple: This function does not work if you open it using the rewrite url. It holds the first blog post ("Hello World") in the $post instead of the speaker post. :(

```
function add_meta() {
  global $post;
  if (get_post_type($post) != "speaker") return;
  echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta');
```

How can I get the speaker post correctly into the normal Wordpress loop? So that other Plugins such as Yoast can work correctly?

### Solution from Milo:

```
add_action("parse_request", 'action_handler'); 
function action_handler($wp) {

  if (isset($wp->query_vars["speaker"]))   {
      $speaker_name = $wp->query_vars["speaker"];

      ... some magic to get the $post_name as their is additional logic needed ...
      $wp->query_vars["speaker"] = $post_name;
  }
}
```

Thank you [Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when the main query is parsed, having just a custom query var set will not result in a successful main query, so it defaults to setting up the home page blog posts query.

To solve this, set the post type query var directly in the rewrite rule and there's no need for those intermediate steps-

```
add_rewrite_rule('slp\/(.*)', 'index.php?speaker=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

You will also need to filter `post_type_link` if you want to hide the original URL when permalinks are output by API functions.

```
function wpd_speaker_links( $url, $post ){
    if ( 'speaker' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        return home_url( "/slp/" . $post->post_name . "/"  );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_speaker_links', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Nice :) THX
As i need to hide the url I tried to hide the post_name e.g.:
domain.tld/speaker/speaker-name-x31z will be translated into
domain.tld/slp/speaker-name. 
This was the reason why i tried the hock "parse_request".
Is their an official way to get hold on the main query to modify it?

Comment: In that case you can add your `parse_request` function back in, but change it to test `isset( $wp->query_vars["speaker"] )` and translate to whatever new value it must be to have the query succeed. `$wp` is passed by reference, so the function does not have to `return` anything, you just set `$wp->query_vars["speaker"]` to equal whatever new value you want it to be.